# Face Detection Using KinectV2 and OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, kinect

Recently I have been trying to learn OpenCV and was trying to detect faces using the Haar Classifier.

I was successful in detecting faces when I obtained the video stream from the default webcam,but when I use Kinect instead of the default webcam, It still detects face but the frame rate drops tremendously.

The code that I've Written is

```
int main() {
    string haar_face = "F:\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml";
    CascadeClassifier haar_cascade;
    haar_cascade.load(haar_face);
    if (haar_cascade.empty()) {
        return -1;
    }
    vector<Rect_<int>> faces;
    bool optionKinect = false;
    cout << "Choose Option\n1.) Kinect \n>1.) WebCam\n";
    int choice;
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 1) {
        optionKinect = true;
    }   
    if (optionKinect) {
    CKinectStreamsMat* kinectStream = new CKinectStreamsMat();
    kinectStream->initSensor();
        while (true) {
            Mat original, gray;
            Mat face;
            Rect face_i;
            //cap >> original;
            original = kinectStream->getColorFrame();
            if (original.data) {
                cvtColor(original, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
                haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces);
                int size = faces.size();
                for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    face_i = faces[i];
                    face = gray(face_i);
                    rectangle(original, face_i, CV_RGB(0, 255, 0), 1);
                }
                imshow("original", original);
                if(waitKey(20) == 27){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        VideoCapture cap(0);
        while (true) {
            Mat original, gray;
            Mat face;
            Rect face_i;
            cap >> original;
            //original = kinectStream->getColorFrame();
            if (original.data) {
                cvtColor(original, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
                haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces);
                int size = faces.size();
                for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    face_i = faces[i];
                    face = gray(face_i);
                    rectangle(original, face_i, CV_RGB(0, 255, 0), 1);
                }
                imshow("original", original);
                if(waitKey(20) == 27){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And this is how I am obtaining the Color frame from Kinect.

```
cv::Mat CKinectStreamsMat::getColorFrame()
{
    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
    IColorFrame* frame = NULL;
    IFrameDescription* frameDesc;
    cv::Mat colorImage;
    hr = _color_reader->AcquireLatestFrame(&frame);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = frame->get_FrameDescription(&frameDesc);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
            int frameWidth = 0, frameHeight = 0;
            hr = frameDesc->get_Width(&frameWidth);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                hr = frameDesc->get_Height(&frameHeight);
            }
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                const int imgSize = frameWidth*frameHeight * 4 * sizeof(unsigned char); //4 Channels(BGRA)
                colorImage = cv::Mat(1080,1920,CV_8UC4);
                hr = frame->CopyConvertedFrameDataToArray(imgSize, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(colorImage.data), ColorImageFormat_Bgra);
            }
        }
        SafeRelease(frameDesc);
        SafeRelease(frame);
    }
    return colorImage;
}
```

I thought the reason for low performance might be the difference in resolution of the frames provided by the WebCam and Kinect, So I also tried scaling down the frame provided by Kinect down to the size that was even less than the frame size of WebCam. But still the performance was very low.

As this is only what I could think of and now I am out of ideas, So could anyone please tell what could be the reason for this low performance?

Comment: If you had the same webcam as your default as not the default one then use that does the problem happen? i.e. is the problem not using the default camera or using Kinect?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder The problem is with the Kinect I guess

Comment: I'd suggest testing this, then you can at least narrow down what you need to solve. I.e. make the Kinect the default camera or it is a problem with the Kinect and you need to look into doing things differently.